# Send mqtt last will with graceful exit

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

[I am aware of a very similar question, but the answers are not helping]

In my scenario it would be helpful to get notified when my client goes offline - no matter if it exits graceful or not. Specifying a last will seemed like a good idea (and following the real-life application of a last will I thought that this will take always take effect).

But when I use `client.disconnect()` the last will is not published.

Now I am wondering how I can solve this problem. On [some pages](https://cedalo.com/blog/mqtt-last-will-explained-and-example/#When_does_the_MQTT_broker_send_the_Last_Will_message) it is stated that this can somehow be configured, so that the last will is sent anyways. My paho-mqtt version is 1.6.1 and [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) states that it implements MQTT 5.0 which is required for that functionality.

But I don't get it working and don't even understand what I should do:

`client.disconnect("disconnect-with-will-message")` not working 
`client.disconnect(0)` not working 
`client.disconnect(1)` not working

Is there a solution other than having a manual publish statement in the case of a graceful exit?

**Solution:**

Using paho-mqtt it needs to be specified that the mqtt5 protocol should be used:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.reasoncodes as reasoncodes
import paho.mqtt.packettypes as packettypes

client = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5)

client.will_set('last/willi')
client.connect('localhost')

client.publish('hello/world')
client.loop()
client.disconnect(reasoncodes.ReasonCodes(packettypes.PacketTypes.DISCONNECT, "Disconnect", 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client.disconnect()` function can take 2 arguments for MQTTv5 clients

`reasoncode` and `properties`

From the [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901208) it says the disconnect-with-will `reasoncode` should be `4`

Comment: Thats a helpful hint, but mosquitto still doesnt log the will getting published, but I will follow that lead.

Sadly, I can't yet upvote ...
Thanks so far! If that turns out to solve the problem I will also accept this answer

Comment: Misinterpreted the paho documentation, it has to be specified that v5 is to be used - now it works - thanks again!